# Ping doesn't work on non-root user

Tags: linux, arch-linux, ping

Ping doesn't work on a non-root user.

```
[ethan@EthanPC yaourt]$ ping -c 3 www.bing.com
ping: unknown host www.bing.com

[root@EthanPC yaourt]# ping -c 3 www.bing.com
PING any.edge.bing.com (204.79.197.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=18.3 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=17.5 ms

--- any.edge.bing.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.546/16.819/18.377/1.647 ms
```

I am using Arch Linux. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you checkd the https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=146249 ?

Comment: Yes I have, `getcap /usr/bin/ping` returns `/usr/bin/ping = cap_net_raw+ep`, and reinstalling `iputils` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you checked SELinux?

Comment: I don't have SELinux installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `ping` itself, but with the OS components involved in resolving domain names to IP addresses. (Notice how it doesn't say "open socket: operation not permitted"; it says "unknown host").

Make sure all these files are readable by everyone, and `chmod a+rX` as needed:

- `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
- `/lib/libnss_dns-*.so`
- **`/etc/resolv.conf`** (usually the problematic one).

Verify with `getent hosts www.bing.com` or `curl https://www.bing.com`.